# How to add UIView Gesture - Programmatically UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have searched a lot about adding a gesture on UIView when it is tapped. There are many solutions but none of them worked for me.

I have made UIView class programmatically and using the view in different classes.

Here is my class of UIView:

class PaymentServiceView: UIView {

```
private let views: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    // view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

private let titleLbl: UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.font = UIFont(name: AppFontName.circularStdRegular, size: 18)
    label.clipsToBounds = true
    return label
}()

private let subLbl: UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.font = UIFont(name: AppFontName.robotoRegular, size: 15)
    label.clipsToBounds = true
    return label
}()

private let image: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

private let btnImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: IconName.chevron_down)?.transform(withNewColor: UIColor.btnGray)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

init(titleLabel: String, subTitleLabel: String, imageName: String) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.addSubview(views)
    self.views.addSubview(btnImage)
    self.views.addSubview(titleLbl)
    self.views.addSubview(image)
    self.views.addSubview(subLbl)
    
    titleLbl.text = titleLabel
    image.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    subLbl.text = subTitleLabel
    
    setupConstraints()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setupConstraints() {
    
    self.views.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.views.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.views.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    self.views.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320).isActive = true
    
    self.image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.views.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.views.leadingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    self.image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    self.image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    
    self.titleLbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.views.centerYAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
    self.titleLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    
    self.subLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    self.subLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    self.subLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnImage.leadingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
    
    btnImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: views.topAnchor, constant: 55).isActive = true
    btnImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: views.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    btnImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
    
}
```

}

Now Im using this UIView class in **PaymentServicesViewController**

```
class PaymentServicesViewController: UIViewController {

private (set) lazy var headerView: HeaderView = { [unowned self] in
    let view = HeaderView.init(titleLbl: Headings.paymentService, closeAction: {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }, nextAction: {
        print("next")
    }, previousAction: {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    })
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

private let fundTransferView: PaymentServiceView = {
    
    let view = PaymentServiceView(titleLabel: Headings.fundTransfer, subTitleLabel: Description.fundTransferDecription , imageName: IconName.fundImage )
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

private let subscriptionView: PaymentServiceView = {

    let view = PaymentServiceView(titleLabel: Headings.subscribe, subTitleLabel: Description.subscriptionDescription, imageName: IconName.subImage )
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

private let billPaymentView: PaymentServiceView = {
    let view = PaymentServiceView(titleLabel: Headings.billPayment, subTitleLabel: Description.billPaymentDescription , imageName: IconName.billImage )
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .gray2

    let fundtrasnferGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(fundTranferTapped))
    fundTransferView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.fundTransferView.addGestureRecognizer(fundtrasnferGesture)
    
    let subscribeGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(subscribeTapped))
    subscriptionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.subscriptionView.addGestureRecognizer(subscribeGesture)

    let billPaymentGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(billPaymentTapped))
    fundTransferView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.billPaymentView.addGestureRecognizer(billPaymentGesture)
    
    view.addSubview(headerView)
    view.addSubview(subscriptionView)
    view.addSubview(fundTransferView)
    view.addSubview(billPaymentView)
    setupConstraint()
}

@objc func fundTranferTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("FundTransfer Tapped.")
}

@objc func subscribeTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Subscribe Tapped.")
}

@objc func billPaymentTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("BillPayment Tapped.")
}


private func setupConstraint() {
    
    headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    
    subscriptionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    subscriptionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    subscriptionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.topAnchor, constant: -130).isActive = true
    
    fundTransferView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    fundTransferView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    
    billPaymentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    billPaymentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    billPaymentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.bottomAnchor, constant: 130).isActive = true
    
}
```

}

I know there is a small mistake I'm doing but not sure. Help would be appreciated, Thank you.

[image]

Comment: We're missing a lot of code / information on how you are laying out the views. **Start simple** -- use a plain `UIView` subclass, with no subviews. Add it to your view and add a gesture recognizer to it. If *that* works, start adding in your other UI elements. Best guess, based on your code and your screen shot, is that your `PaymentServiceView` ends up with an actual size of `.zero`, and the subviews are outside the bounds.

Comment: it works on simple UIView. PaymentServicesView is a UIView class I made because most of the screens have the same design so I made one and use it in different classes. PaymentServicesView has constraints that I have not added to the post. It just creates a view with a label and image as you can see in the picture.  now in PaymentServiceVC, I'm implementing the view. Subviews are actually initialized in PaymentServiceViewController.

Comment: OK - then it sounds like you are doing something with your constraints that is causing problems. Add your `setupConstraints()` and `setupConstraint()` funcs so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I have edited the code. You can copy and paste and run it at your side to check. PaymentServiceView is UIView class that has a UIView, a label, a sublabel, and an image. Implementing this class in PaymentServicesViewController and giving constraints for the UIView only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple constraints...

If you add this at the end of `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    subscriptionView.clipsToBounds = true
    fundTransferView.clipsToBounds = true
    billPaymentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

You'll see that the views "disappear":

[image]

because they have no Width or Height constraints (so their size is `.zero`).

In `setupConstraints()` in your `PaymentServiceView` class, add these two lines:

```
    self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.views.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.views.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now, the `PaymentServiceView` will be the same Width and Height as `self.views` view.

However, now that the views have Heights:

[image]

your layout needs to be adjusted.

Change the `.clipsToBounds` back to `false` (remove those added lines) so the shadows won't be clipped, and change these constraints in your controller (adjust the `15` and `-15` to your liking):

```
    //subscriptionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.topAnchor, constant: -130).isActive = true
    subscriptionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

    //billPaymentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.bottomAnchor, constant: 130).isActive = true
    billPaymentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fundTransferView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```

and we get:

[image]

Now, because the views have a size, the Tap Gestures will work.

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much DonMag. I figured it out just a min before your answer. I started looking into constraints as per your advice and didn't give constraints to the parent view (self). I never thought it could be a problem of constraints because UI was exactly as I wanted.  Thank you for helping, and sorry I cannot do thumbs-up due to less reputation but I have checked the answer. Instead of giving width and height of self according to the self.views. I gave height and width to self and added self.views constraints to the parent self (top, bottom, trailing and leading)